# how to use SSD for streaming videos, while storing on HDDs

Tags: ssd, streaming, video-streaming

I run a video hosting, youtube like site.
I currently run it with 2x3TB HDDs and they max out at 150mB/s

I`m willing to achieve higher speeds and I think of storing the data on HDDs and streaming them via SSD disk.

How can this be achieved? Can there be multiple backend servers that store data?

Thanks!

Comment: what %age of your catalogue is read? what's your cache hit ratio? how much capacity do you want/need? I do exactly this kind of thing professionally and it's not a quick answer.

Comment: @Chopper3 Pfft, you claim to do this stuff professionally but you still ask boring questions. Just tell the man how to serve his wares ultra quick. I'd guess he needs to RAID0 everything or something

Comment: @dan haha :) I suspect someone's not read the first paragraph of the FAQ *again*

Comment: I can't see how a question like this can be answered is a useful way. There are too many dependencies to the usage pattern, budget, hardware, etc.

Comment: Amazon EC2 or other CDN will improve your speeds way more for less.

Answer (score 4):

This is going to cost you a shedload, but basically, you either need a huge SSD array, or a huge tiered storage array.  There's a bunch of SAN vendors who'll be able to provide you something to meet your requirements, but basically you need:

Many SATA disks, for storage capacity, fronted by SAS 15k disks, or SAS SSDs, for quick access storage.

All provided over 8Gbit Fibrechannel to your webservers.

Answer (score 0):

Two simple choice:

- If you are using Linux on the server(s), check out version 3.9, includes SSD caching. Or maybe check out Bcache.
- Store the hot/popular videos on SSD

Comment: Thing is, you *really* don't want to be data wrangling the popular videos manually.. That's why you need a tiered storage provider, something that automatically migrates data

Comment: @TomO'Connor where can I get one?

Comment: Yes, if he has the budget for them. Though SSD caching its not manual.